# Date validation using javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I am trying to write the validation for a date, where the user has to select a future date and not a past date. My code seems to work only when I use a date from last month (e.g. `26/11/2011`). This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   function mydate()
   {           
       var d= new Date ();
       var day= d.getDate ();

       var mon=d.getMonth ();

       var year= d.getFullYear ();

       var dateformat= day+"/"+mon+"/"+year ;

       var get= document.getElementById("txt").value; 

       if(get >= dateformat )
       {
          alert ('yes valid');
       }
       else 
       {
            alert('Date should greater than to date ');
       }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the date values as strings. This is a textual comparison not a date-wise comparison so it will pretty much **never** work except by coincidence.  You need to parse the date value the user enters into a `Date` data type and do a comparison that way.

Whenever possible you should avoid writing date manipulation code yourself and try to leverage a known working solution, e.g. the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: Mr. bobbymcr can we place both javascript and asp.net validation controls in the same page for different controls.

Comment: I am neither a Javascript nor ASP.NET expert, but I'm pretty sure you can do it. You may run into difficulties, e.g. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088770/asp-net-mixing-server-controls-with-client-controls